# Fixed footer that won't go past bottom of content

Tags: css, positioning

I am trying to get a footer that will always stay at the bottom of the viewport if the content is longer than the viewport. If the content doesn't stretch to the bottom of the viewport, then the footer will stay at the bottom of the content.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- variable content and other divs in here -->
    <div id="footersurround">
        <div id="footerparent"> 
            <div id="footer"></div>
            <div id="linkshome"><!-- links in here --></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```css
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 1024px;
    margin: -512px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#footersurround {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: inherit; /* I want this to take the same value as the wrappers height if I set it to a value(e.g 768px) it works perfectly but when setting it to inherit it will stretch the whole viewport even if the wrapper does not*/
}

#footerparent {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 30;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 60px;
    width: 1024px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    z-index: 16;
}

#linkshome {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -47px;
    min-height: 47px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1074px;
    z-index: 17;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key would be to compare viewport height with document scroll height and set the footer's position (absolute or fixed) accordingly. Here's something I knocked up (jQuery assumed).

```
<head>
    <script src='jquery.js'></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var footer = $('footer'), doc = document.documentElement || document.body;
        footer.css('position', doc.scrollHeight <= $(window).height() ? 'absolute' : 'fixed');
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    body { margin: 0; }
    section { height: 600px; margin-top: 50px; border: solid 1px; position: relative; padding: 10px 10px 40px 10px; }
    footer { bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 30px; background: red; left: 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>main content here</h1>
        <footer></footer>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Utkanos, I've got that all working now. However I was wondering if you or anyone else knows if there is way do solve this problem only with css? A bit like the solution I was attempting before? as I would rather not have to use Javscript as i always seem to have issues ensuring it runs on IE.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: thanks, but im not after a sticky footer but a fixed footer that will stick to the bottom of the content if the content is smaller than the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer (`#footersurround`) already has `position: fixed`, just give it `bottom: 0` instead of `top: 0`. No need to set `width`, `height` and `max-height`. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcG8Y/).

Comment: But he also wants the footer to snap to the bottom of the content container when the content does not fill the whole viewport height. Position fixe would root it to the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: You're right... But I think it's a fair price to pay to avoid a js solution.